# Script reads text file partially on a scheduled execution

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, file-read

I've encountered a strange issue at PythonAnyWhere.com:
File is read normally by a script on manual execution, but only partially on a scheduled execution:

### Script

```
items_list=[]
with open(file) as f: 
    i=1
    for line in f:
        print 'line {0}.: {1}'.format(i, line)
        if i>4:
            temp = line.split()
            single_tuple = temp[0],temp[5]  
            items_list.append(single_tuple)
        i+=1
print items_list
```

### File to read

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.

.google.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1507718426  NID  7gVyyZ0xNYH0Rnrvjr
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1512945206  VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE  CgHkhNJriN0
```

Result in manual exec.:

```
line 1.: # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
line 2.: # http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
line 3.: # This is a generated file!  Do not edit.
line 4.: 
line 5.: .google.com TRUE / FALSE   1507718426  NID  Ixa47gVyyZ0xNYH0Rnrvjr
line 6.: .youtube.com   TRUE  /  FALSE  1512945206  VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE      CgHkhNJriN0

 [('.google.com', 'NID', ), ('.youtube.com', 'VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE' )]
```

Result in scheduled exec. (log):

```
 line 1.: # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
 line 2.: # http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
 line 3.: 
 []
 2017-04-11 11:02:09 -- Completed task, took 1.00 seconds, return code was 1.
```

**What might be a problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is most likely due to a different working directory when you are running the script vs when you are running the scheduled task. try using the full path for your file and see if that fixes it?

https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NoSuchFileOrDirectory

Comment: you were right. I took me to use full path to the cookie file in `with open([*full path*]) as f:` construction. Where *full path* is:  `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(___file___)) ,  'cookie_file.txt')`